# Can we mention the count or list of actual moderators in the election page?

Tags: feature-request, moderators, moderator-election

I was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/election/9?tab=nomination. I could read:

> moderator positions available: 2

But there were no direct indication of the current count or list of moderators. I took me a few minutes to find [that page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) with the desired information.

Can we mention the count or a link to the list of actual moderators in the election page?

Comment: Not sure that it matters. Why does the number of current moderators have a bearing on which ones you will vote to elect?